# Sinch SDK - iOS app does not receive immediate callback when callee reject the call

Tags: ios, capacitor, sinch

I integrated Sinch SDK into iOS application (Capacity plugin which works under ionic).

Main use case so far is to make call from App to phone.
I followed instructions from here: https://developers.sinch.com/docs/in-app-calling/getting-started/ios/create-app/ and everything works correctly - I can call from the app to phones using Sinch platform.

The problem which I noticed is when callee rejects the call then app does not receive immediate notification about it. Sometimes notification (`func callDidEnd(_ call: SinchRTC.SinchCall)`) is triggered after some delay (10-20s). However sometimes when callee rejects the call app is still calling and second connection appears on callee's phone - then when second time callee rejects the call app correctly receive callback about it and close the connection.

Do you have any hints what can be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

We will review the tutorial to see if the issue can be replicated.

However using the `VideoCallKitSwift` Swift sample you can change the following to the sinch client on start and call invocation to make a PSTN call:

In CallKitMediator

add the cli:`<YOURCLI>` after userId in the SinchRTC.client (In this case I have put a placeholder `+4100000000` in the cli)

From

```
 do {
      self.client = try SinchRTC.client(withApplicationKey: APPLICATION_KEY,
                                        environmentHost: ENVIRONMENT_HOST,
                                        userId: userId)
```

To

```
   do {
      self.client = try SinchRTC.client(withApplicationKey: APPLICATION_KEY,
                                        environmentHost: ENVIRONMENT_HOST,
                                         userId: userId,
                                         cli:"+4100000000")
```

In `CallKitMediator+CXProviderDelegate` Here remove the `withId:` and change the client method to `callPhoneNumber` instead of `videoCallToUser`

From

```
let callResult = self.client!.callClient.videoCallToUser(withId: action.handle.value)
```

To

```
let callResult = self.client!.callClient.callPhoneNumber(action.handle.value)
```

Testing to a PSTN connection via this method yields no delay in the `callDidEnd`.   If your issues persist, I would recommend to open a ticket with Sinch support who can analyse the PSTN leg of the call for you.

Comment: It turned out all Sinch methods must be called on main thread and ionic implicitely called in on some background thread causing such issues.

Comment: Yes, this is also documented as important  in the reference documentation. I guess that is where you found it.  https://download.sinch.com/ios/5.19.19/reference/Protocols/SINCall.html